# Delete button only shown halfway from under cell

Tags: uitableview, ios7

[image]

As seen in the link above, when editing = YES, you are able to select circles, which then slide the cell over to reveal the delete button. However, it only reveals the delete button half way.

When sliding to the left to reveal the delete button (editing = NO), the delete button will reside to show itself fully open.

How can I ensure that the delete button will be 100% visible?

(This is only an issue in iOS 7 because of the new delete style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I went in to the storyboard and pinned the tableView to all four sides of the ViewController.